The <select> and <option> elements are not properly removed from the DOM when added dynamically
I have rendered the  element and the  element dynamically based on the button click.
When i have tried to destroy the elements I have faced detached select and option elements issue in memory tab.
I have used the below code.
<body>
      <input class='e-input' id="inputMy"></input>
      
      <button id="open">Update select</button>
      <button id="option">Update Options</button>
      <br><br>
      <button id="destroy">Destroy</button>
  </body>

function Destroy() {
  if (optionElement) {
    selectEle.remove(optionElement);
    selectEle.innerHTML = '';
    optionElement = null;
  }
  inputElement.removeChild(selectEle);
  selectEle = null;
}
function updateOptions() {
  optionElement = document.createElement('option');
  selectEle.appendChild(optionElement);
}

function updateSelectOptions() {
  inputElement = document.getElementById('inputMy');
  selectEle = document.createElement('select');
  selectEle.setAttribute('id', 'selectMy');
  inputElement.appendChild(selectEle);
}

I have tried the remove() method for remove the option element and tried the removeChild() for remove the select element.
but the elements were not destroyed properly.
enter image description here
